# jQuery date format not work on table column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm populating table from data in database as below.

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.expenses}" var="expense">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%;"><a
                href="expense_manage?expense_id=${expense.expenseId}"
                class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
            <td id="date">${expense.expenseDate}</td>
            <td>${expense.expenseDesc}</td>
            <td>${expense.expenseAmount}</td>
            <td>${expense.comment}</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">
                <button type="button"
                    onclick="ConfirmDelete('id=${expense.expenseId}','removeExpense')"
                    class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

I need to format date display in above table as `yyyy-MM-dd`. so i added this.

```
<script src="js/jquery-dateFormat.min.js"></script>

    <script>    
        jQuery(function() {
            var shortDateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';

            jQuery("#date").each(
                    function(idx, elem) {
                        if (jQuery(elem).is(":input")) {
                            jQuery(elem).val(
                                    jQuery.format.date(jQuery(elem).val(),
                                            shortDateFormat));
                        } else {
                            jQuery(elem).text(
                                    jQuery.format.date(jQuery(elem).text(),
                                            shortDateFormat));
                        }
                    });
        });
    </script>
```

But it changes only date in first row. Others are not changing.

[image: data table]

How can i fix this ?

Comment: you are using jquery-dateFormat.min.js for format date only???

Comment: @ling.s Sorry ? not clear your question.

Comment: why you are using jquery-dateFormat.min.js?

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: @ling.s to format date display on tables, input fields.

Comment: Instead of using `jquery-dateFormat.min.js` you can simply write a simple function to format date

Comment: @ling.s can you explain how can i do it ? because i'm new to this.

Comment: refer http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is unique in a document. To group elements, use classes.

Replace

```
<td id="date">${expense.expenseDate}</td>
```

by

```
<td class="date">${expense.expenseDate}</td>
```

and replace

```
jQuery("#date").each(
```

by

```
jQuery(".date").each(
```